# Can AWS Transcoder merge an audio file and a video file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, audio, video, ffmpeg, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm interested in capturing video via html5.  The problem is that the video is captured separately from the audio.  So to produce a video with audio, one must merge them together.  It appears that ffmpeg will do the trick.

Does anyone know if AWS Transcoder will perform this operation as well?

Answer (score 0):

AWS transcoder can only accept 1 file. There is no way to merge 2. Have you tried ffmpeg?